# Скрывать/Показывать формы по условию switch-a

Tags: php, ajax

```
    $states = [
                'on'  => ['value' => true, 'text' => 'ON', 'color' => 'primary'],
                'off' => ['value' => false, 'text' => 'OFF', 'color' => 'default'],
            ];
 $form->switch('colorSelectEnable', trans('admin.ColorSelectEnable'))->states($states);
```

и есть поля которые в зависимости от значения $states должны скрываться или показываться, как это можно реализовать на уровне контроллера?

Comment: Что это вообще такое? Если какой-то фреймворк, то добавьте название в теги.

Comment: Извиняюсь, это админка z-song от Laravel